# Detecting links in text and determine whether it is a image

Tags: javascript

How to i detect urls in text and determine if the urls are images?

I would like to do this in javascript if possible. Basically i have a  and my users will enter their comments. Some of the time they will paste links of images.

I would like to preview image if the url is a image. checking for extensions might not be the solution that i want because .php extension could give a image as well.

Comment: You could use regular expressions to search the text for urls ending in jpg,tif,bmp,gif,...

Comment: Which language do you want to do this in? Is any one of the three you tagged your question with OK? What is your criteria for "if the urls are images" - just a test for common image extensions like ".jpg" or ".png", or do you want to actually retrieve the resource at that url and check its format?

Comment: Agreed. You really should explain what language you are doing this in, and for what purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How well do you want to recognize url's? If you require that the url's contain 'http://' or 'https://' then the problem is fairly straightforward. Simply split the text (using the str.split() function) and search each list element to see if it contains the keywords ('http://', or whatever you decide to use). To determine whether the target url is an image, simply use the list comprehensions (i.e. some_url[-3:]) to get the file extension at the end of that list item.  Then match that file extension against a list of known image file extensions.

Comment: yup that's what i eventually did. i learned that an event, "error", will be fired if the src attribute of <img> tag is not a image. so my work-around is to rely on this "error" event, if the event fired off, i will remove my <img> DOM from the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [getimagesize](http://de.php.net/getimagesize) function, which returns an array with 7 elements if that file is image and returns FALSE on failure.